# Check RDP port number remotely

Tags: powershell

I am writing a script to check details of Remote desktop connection.

```
$ts = Get-WMIObject Win32_TerminalServiceSetting -ComputerName $s -Namespace ROOT\CIMV2\TerminalServices
```

With above script i can check if RDP is enabled or not. But i need to check which port will be used in RDP.

I am aware that 3389 port is used but in my environment some servers, RDP is configured on other ports.

I need to fetch that port number. I checked in `ROOT\CIMV2\TerminalServices` WMI Class but port number detail is not there.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\WinStations\RDP-Tcp
```

On this location i can see there is a dword (**PortNumber**) that contain the port number details.

Can we check some other way because by checking registry we need to use remote registry service which is running but sometimes they are stopped and we can't start it.

Comment: Sometimes you just need to access the registry.

Comment: Found your other post: https://serverfault.com/questions/888875/powershell-check-rdp-port-number-remotely

Comment: You could also use `new-object System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient($host, 3389)` to test if the port is open. If it's not the command will throw an exception.